# Unable to connect to Samba shares after upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, upgrade, samba

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 due to an issue with a new motherboard/cpu that prevented multiple monitors from working at the same time, I find that I'm no longer to connect to my samba file shares, from either of the Blu-ray players (the main reason I bought those specific ones) and not even from the same exact computer browsing by network.

> Failed to retrieve share list from server: Invalid Argument

I've tried a few fixes I've found, adding first

```
client min protocol = NT1
```

then removing that and trying

```
client min protocol = SMB2
client max protocol = SMB3
min protocol = SMB2
max protocol = SMB3
```

restarting smbd and winbind, and nothing has worked from either localhost browse or the blu-ray players

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

I originally didn't post the question because I found something very similar, but now that I've found the answer, I'm not allowed to post it on that question because my reputation isn't high enough. So here:

None of the options around setting client level helped, and it occurred to me later that I'm attempting to connect TO Ubuntu (from a BluRay player) so it's the server settings that are important, not client, so instead of

```
client min protocol = core
```

or

```
client min protocol = NT1
```

What I needed was

```
server min protocol = NT1
```

But it still didn't help.

I upped the logging level in Samba to try to understand what was happening, because I didn't have access to logs on the blu-ray player, so using

```
log level = 3 passdb:5 auth:5
```

Confirmed that my issue was negotiating the protocol `Requested protocol [NT LM 0.12]  Server exit (no protocol supported)`

But all of the fixes for that still didn't work.  What finally did the trick was to purge samba and samba common entirely (copy the share details into a notepad first, backup files in /etc/samba get wiped in the purge of samba.common)

From [How do I re-install Samba?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225786/how-do-i-re-install-samba)

```
sudo apt-get purge samba samba-common
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install samba
```

This still didn't fix it - I added the shares and confirmed I could access it from another computer, but still nothing from the Blu-ray player

I turned on logging again and then finally tried

```
server min protocol = NT1
```

again, and with the fresh install of Samba, it connected and worked fine.

I added this all here because I wasn't allowed to post the answer on the other question, so hopefully it will still be found and be useful.  As much of a hassle as it was for me to investigate, I didn't want to just give up and let other people have to figure it out.